# How to print current date in JSP?

Tags: jsp, date-format

I want to do something like this:

```
 <?php echo date('Y'); ?>
```

But then in a `.jsp` file. All the [tutorials](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/21.html) I'm seeing require building a class somewhere. We're running appFuse and Tapestry. Surely one of those (if not Java itself) provide us with something to do this sort of thing without all that overhead.

This seems like it should work, but doesn't:

```
 <%= new Date.getYear() %>
```

Comment: There seems to be some confusion of ideas here. You're either using Tapestry or you're using JSPs, but hardly both, or are you?

Comment: Well, given that I don't know what I'm doing :), yes, I'm editing both .jsp and .tml files, depending. The rough page frame is mostly jsps so far, e.g. default.jsp, header.jsp, footer.jsp. I'm assuming the page content will be more .tml. (The framework was set-up for me by someone else.)

Comment: Interesting mixture. Good luck :)

Comment: heh. thanks. yeah, know which files to touch, and which to leave alone, and what goes where is always the hardest part about learning these things... :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use `jsp:useBean` to construct a `java.util.Date` instance and use JSTL [`fmt:formatDate`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) to format it into a human readable string using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
Current year is: <fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" />
```

The old fashioned *scriptlet* way would be:

```
<%= new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new java.util.Date()) %>
```

Note that you need to specify the full qualified class name when you don't use `@page import` directives, that was likely the cause of your problem. Using *scriptlets* is however highly [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) since a decade.

This all is demonstrated in the [`[jsp]` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) as well :)

Comment: @BalusC: do you sell t-shirts saying "BalusC fan" ? coz I'd buy one! :)

Answer (score 3):

`<%= new java.util.Date().getYear() + 1900 %>`

Comment: While short and applies directly to the question, note that this is a scriptlet, which BalusC already mentioned is discouraged.

Comment: Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@page import="java.util.GregorianCalendar"%>
    <%
      GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
      out.print(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    %>
```

Comment: One liner: `<% out.print((new java.util.GregorianCalendar()).get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR));  %>`

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 to print year you can use:

```
<%= LocalDate.now().getYear() %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page import="java.time.LocalDate"%>

${LocalDate.now().year}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should be writing JSPs using [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) and using its `<fmt>` tags to format dates and such.