# java script for generating dropdown list dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a list for choosing years in drop down, how can generate list dynamically.

my code :

```
 <select  id="year1">
     <option value=2012>2012</option>
     <option value=2011>2011</option>
     <option value=2010>2010</option>
 </select>
```

i have written a script like this,

```
 for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {  
     document.getElementById('year1').options[i] = new Option(curr_year-i+1,curr_year-i+1);
 }
```

my doubt is how can give values here,( i.e  < option value= "2012">2012 ) dynamically. thanks in advance.
note: for me taking value in the option is important.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var year = 2013;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){        
    $("#year1").get(0).options[$("#year1").get(0).options.length] = new Option(year, year);
        year=year+1;
    }
});
```

Here the year value is incremental, for reverse order use `year=year-1;`

And here is the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XpfAr/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery `append` to append options to select.Here is how you do it dynamically

```
var x = 2012;
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    $('#ddl').append($('<option></option>').val(x).html(x));
    x=x+1;
}
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/taAtA/)

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this by using only php 
Just try this,

```
<select  id="year1">
   <?php $current_year=date("Y");
   for($i=1900;$i<=$current_year;$i++){
      <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
   } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: give same instance in jsp ?

Comment: @user2773010 by using jsp you can just replace the variables and displaying of variables

Comment: you we cant do in jsp ?

Comment: @user2773010 ref :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685952/how-to-print-the-year-in-a-jsp

Comment: <select  id="year1">
       int current_year=2013;
       for(int i=1900;int i<=current_year;int i++){
          <option value=+"i"+>+i+</option>
       }
    </select>

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript

```
var createComboBox = function()
{
    var select = document.createElement("select"),
        year = new Date().getFullYear();

    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {  
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        select.appendChild(option).text = year;
        select.appendChild(option).value = year;
        year += -1
    }

    document.body.appendChild(select);
}

createComboBox();
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WBQJ4/)