# Display date in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

In a jsp i would like to display the date of the year

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" pattern="yyyy" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}"  />
```

but i get

```
for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert 4/22/14 5:23 PM of type class     java.util.Date to Number
```

i saw on [How to print current date in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685952/how-to-print-the-year-in-a-jsp) this is the way to go

so i don't really understand.

Answer (score 3):

**Your issue**

```
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" pattern="yyyy" />
```

Should be

```
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
```

And

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}"  />
```

Should be

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy"/>
```

**Why?**

You're declaring a new `Date` object with the `jsp:useBean` tag. This does not require a pattern; `Date` is stored in it's own format. The pattern comes in when you want to *output* that `Date` object, using the `fmt:formatDate` tag. This requires a pattern so it knows how to output the date as a `String`, to the view.

Comment: It worked for me.. Remove other code except above three lines (suggested by @christopher) from your jsp and run it.